# How do I prove this function is differentiable at 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
x^{4/3}\cos \left(\frac1x\right) & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\\\
   0       & \text{if } x =0.
  \end{cases}$$
Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

I tried taking a two-sided limit test, but I was unable to simplify it. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just observe that, for $x \neq0$, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|=\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|=\left|x^{1/3}\cos \left(\frac1x\right)\right|\leq\left|x^{1/3}\right|\to 0.
$$